# Why IoScheduler using ScheduledExecutorService with the poolCoreSize is 1?

Tags: rx-java2

I found the IoScheduler.createWorker() will create a NewThreadWorker immediately if there is no cached NewThreadWorker，This may result in OutOfMemoryError.

If I put 1000 count of work to IoScheduler one-time，it will create 1000   count of NewThreadWorker and ScheduledExecutorService.

```java
private void submitWorkers(int workerCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++) {
        Single.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return "String-call(): " + Thread.currentThread().hashCode();
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                        // TODO
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

If I set the workerCount with 1000, I received a OutOfMemoryError，I want to know why IoScheduler use NewThreadWorker with  ScheduledExecutorService but just execute a single work。
Every time a new work is coming it will create a NewThreadWorker and ScheduledExecutorService if there is no cached NewThreadWorker，Why is it designed to be such a process?

Answer (score 1):

The standard workers of RxJava each use a dedicated thread to avoid excessive thread hopping and work migration in flows.

The standard IO scheduler uses an unbounded number of worker threads because it's main use is to allow blocking operations to block a worker thread while other operations can commence on other worker threads. The difference from newThread is that there is a thread reuse allowed once a worker is returned to an internal pool.

If there was a limit on the number of threads, it would drastically increase the likelihood of deadlocks due to resource exhaustion. Also, unlike the computation scheduler, there is no good default number for this limit: 1, 10, 100, 1000?

There are several ways to work around this problem, such as:

- use [`Schedulers.from()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#from-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) with an arbitrary `ExecutorService` which you can limit and configure as you wish,
- use `ParallelScheduler` from the [Extensions project](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#parallelscheduler) and define an arbitrary large but fixed pool of workers.